# Assigns the value of each td in the table with a random unique number with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, random, shuffle

I have a function that can generate a unique random number, the result is stored in an array. my question. How can each number be entered in rows td when there is a click event.

```js
function random(max, min) {
  arr = [];
  for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    x = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
    if (arr.includes(x) == true) {
      i = i - 1;
    } else {
      if (x > max == false) {
        arr.push(x);
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;

}
```

For example, I have a table that has 3 rows

```html
<button class="btn btn-md btn-danger" id="shuffle">Loop</button>
<table class="table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col">#</th>
         <th scope="col">First</th>
         <th scope="col">Last</th>
         <th scope="col">Number</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">1</th>
         <td>Mark</td>
         <td>Otto</td>
         <td name="random"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">2</th>
         <td>Jacob</td>
         <td>Thornton</td>
         <td name="random"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">3</th>
         <td>Larry</td>
         <td>the Bird</td>
         <td name="random"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

And trigger code

```js
$('#shuffle').on('click', function (e) {
  var td = $('td[name="random"]');
  td.each((key, value) => {
    value.value = random(3, 1); // this's just example
  });

});
```

Comment: Why not generate a random number just on click? Do you need a prepared array before click?

Comment: Your `random()` function has logical errors. I know you must be proud of it but its buggy. Never change the control var in a `for` loop, you do `i = i - 1;
`. Use a `while` loop instead.

Comment: @mardubbles a `for` is just syntaxical sugar for a `while` loop.

Comment: @freedomn-m not really. A `for` loop *changes* the control var. A `while` loop just wants `true`. Why are you even challenging this?

Comment: "just wants true" as does a for loop / "for changes the var" - only if you add the `;i++` which you don't have to and is the same as putting `i++;` at the end of the while loop.  `for (var i = 0; i<10; ++i)` == `var i = 0; while (i<10) { ... ++i; }`

Comment: Ok @freedomn-m, and also `break` could change logic, or `return`. Or any number of infinite number of `if` statements inside it to call the latter.

Comment: But you do have a point @freedomn-m. I respect your logic.